# Lightweight stateful server session vs. stateless token (that requires server revocation list)

Tags: rest, session, asp.net-web-api, token, stateless

When I use server stateful sessions, I always use it for lightweight purposes, such as just storing the userid, name, timezone, and last page hit of the user. For 10,000 users, this might end up being ~3MB. It's not much memory, it is easy to keep in sync with other servers, and it is easy to log out/revocate the sessionid.

It seems that if I used a stateless token such as JWT, I would need to check the token for every request to the server and see if it's on a revocation list. And that revocation list would have to have at least two fields, the token id, and how long the token was originally valid for (so that the entry could be eventually removed, otherwise the revocation list would always just grow). Also, I am sure for security reasons, users need to know all sessions logged in, so I would still need to keep details on every active token, including the userid it is for and the last page hit for the token.

So, are there benefits to using stateless token (that requires server revocation list) vs a lightweight stateful server session?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of benefits of a truly stateless server:

1. Scaling. Having to replicate the state, however small it is will limit the number of nodes.
2. Load balancing. If you don't replicate the state, you have to use sticky sessions (same user always connects to the same instance), which will eventually cause uneven loads.
3. Rolling updates. When updating servers one-by-one (if you do continuous delivery for example) both session replication and sticky sessions will make things more complicated, possibly prevent rolling updates altogether.

Anyway, I guess if you can schedule downtimes for updates, have a limited amount of users, having a stateful session will not be a problem, and may be easier to implement.

These benefits apply to cryptographic tokens like JWT, where there is no server session required. A revocation list complicates things, but as it does not need to be stored on any specific server, it does not interfere.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about a stateless token that requires server revocation list. What are the benefits of that over a lightweight stateful server session?

Comment: I've looked at the benefits of a truly stateless server, and it seems to be a red herring-- isn't a revocation list almost always required? And if so, then it's not really stateless, right?

Comment: Fair enough. I meant that those advantages that I listed actually apply to (crypto) Token-based solutions. Any solution where the server itself does not require a state has those features that I listed. A revocation list can be shared easily, for example through a database, so it does not need to be stored at the server which generates the token.